# Universal property of $A_{\mathrm{cris}}/p^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, p-adic-hodge-theory, crystalline-cohomology, divided-powers

It is well known that the ring $A_{\mathrm{cris}}$ of Fontaine is the universal $p$-adically complete divided power thickening of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$; in fact, this is one possible definition for $A_{\mathrm{cris}}$. Why does it follow, as is claimed without proof at the end of section 2.1.2 of Fontaine's "Le corps de periodes p-adiques," that $A_{\mathrm{cris}}/p^n$ is the universal divided power thickening of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}/p^n$ over $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$?

Let me rephrase the question more concretely: for every surjection $R \twoheadrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}/p^n$ of $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$-algebras whose kernel is equipped with a divided power structure that is compatible with that on $p\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ we want to produce a unique morphism $A_{\mathrm{cris}}/p^n \rightarrow R$ that is compatible with divided powers and with morphisms towards $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}/p^n$. Such would surely exist by the universal property of $A_{\mathrm{cris}}$ if $R$ lifted to a $p$-adically complete divided power thickening $\widetilde{R} \twoheadrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, but does it always lift like so? And why?

The question is basic and must be well-known to experts, but I think it would nevertheless be worthwhile to clarify this point because the literature is usually terse about this.

Comment: Consider the fiber-product ring $R \times_{O_C/(p^n)} O_C$ with an evident surjection onto $O_C$ whose kernel coincides with $\ker(R \rightarrow O_C/(p^n))$.